# Can you set events to be private by default in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, privacy

Is it possible to set your Google Calendar events to be private by default?  I don't want to mindlessly add public items to the calendar.

Comment: A "public" event means that details are allowed to be synced to other service or devices and can be seen when you share the calendar. They aren't listed publicly or accessible to the general public.

Comment: hmm I see your point...I've marked a few items as private however, and I'm still able to pull them in on my iPod Touch.

Comment: Some older syncing utilities ignore private flags, just like GCal itself doesn't sync FB events properly when they're private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very slow answer here, but you can always [make your calendar private](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37535), which will prevent anyone from searching for and seeing your events.

You can also make your calendar public, but default to only show `free/busy` statuses.

> When you select Make this calendar public, all of your events will
>   appear in the public search results of Google Calendar and Google.
>   Additionally, others will be able to view the calendar and its public
>   events with your Calendar Address, or by adding the calendar to their
>   'Calendars' list.
>
> Making your calendar public and selecting See only free/busy (hide
>   details) means that your calendar information will not appear in the
>   search results of any Google Calendar or Google search. Additionally,
>   only your free/busy information will be visible to those who access
>   your calendar at its address, or by adding it to their 'Calendars'
>   list.
>
> To keep your calendar private and only shared with the people you
>   designate, be sure the 'Make this calendar public' option is not
>   selected. For information on sharing your calendar with specific
>   people, please visit this [page](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37082).